# Am I initializing twice?

Tags: objective-c, multiple-instances

I have the following class:

```
@interface Object2D : NSObject
{
    Point2D* position;
    Vector2D* vector;
    FigureType figure;
    CGSize size;
}

@property (assign) Point2D* position;
@property (assign) Vector2D* vector;
@property (assign) CGSize size;

...

@end
```

And its implementation:

```
@implementation Object2D

@synthesize position;
@synthesize vector;
@synthesize size;

- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        position = [[Point2D alloc] init];
        vector = [[Vector2D alloc] init];
        size.width = kDefaultSize;
        size.height = kDefaultSize;
    }

    return self;
}
```

When I create an instance of `Object2D`, I'm doing this:

```
- (void) init
{
    // Create a ball 2D object in the upper left corner of the screen
    // heading down and right
    ball = [[Object2D alloc] init];
    ball.position = [[Point2D alloc] initWithX:0.0 Y:0.0];
    ball.vector = [[Vector2D alloc] initWithX:5.0 Y:4.0];

}
```

I'm not sure if I'm initializing two `Point2D` objects and two `Vector2D` objects, because I make an instance of Point2D and Vector2d in Object2D init method.

```
@class Vector2D;

@interface Point2D : NSObject
{
    CGFloat X;
    CGFloat Y;
}


@interface Vector2D : NSObject
{
    CGFloat angle;
    CGFloat length;
    Point2D* endPoint;
}
```

Classes Object2D, Point2D and Vector2D don't have dealloc method.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are. Also if you have the 'retain' attribute on the properties then lines like this...

```
ball.position = [[Point2D alloc] initWithX:0.0 Y:0.0];
```

are memory leaks you need either...

```
ball.position = [[[Point2D alloc] initWithX:0.0 Y:0.0] autorelease];
```

or

```
Point2D *point = [[Point2D alloc] initWithX:0.0 Y:0.0];
ball.position = point;
[point release];
```

Comment: I've updated my question adding `Object2D`implementation. The properties has assign attribute.

Comment: Still creating two instances and also your allocations in the init method are leaking, as soon as you assign those variables to other objects, as you do when you create an instance of Object2D and call ball.position =  etc etc then the original objects are leaking.

Comment: I will not init these objects on init method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are creating two instances of each of those classes. And they do have `dealloc` methods built in, even if you haven't declared them yourself. I would make X and Y **properties** of the Point2D class so that you can change them without your `initWithX:Y:` method, just by using `aPoint.X`, etc.

More generally, I would suggest avoiding using Objective-C objects as you've done here. When your data can be easily contained in a struct, it can make your code more streamlined to dodge the crazy world of Objective-C methods and memory management.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. They are classes because they have methods.

Comment: I see. I misinterpreted your last code snippet as being the full interface code.